# Solve the inequality $\frac{2}{3x-1} ≥ \frac{1}{x-1}-\frac{1}{x+1}$

Tags: functions, inequality

> Solve the inequality $\frac{2}{3x-1} ≥ \frac{1}{x-1}-\frac{1}{x+1}$. Answer : $S=(-1,0] \cup\left(\frac{1}{3},1\right) \cup [3;+∞)$

Here is what I did:

$\frac{2}{3x-1}≥\frac{x+1-(x-1)}{(x-1)(x+1)}$

$\frac{2}{3x-1}≥\frac{2}{x^{2}-1}$

$\frac{2x^{2}-2}{3x-1}≥2$

$\frac{2x^{2}-2}{3x-1}-2≥0$

$\frac{2x^{2}-6x}{3x-1}≥0$

But I don't know what to do now.

Comment: Oh sorry! Understood the answer properly. I misinterpreted the sign of union.

Comment: "I got this" How did you? Please expand on your computations.

Comment: @Did OK. Just a sec

Comment: @Did done, maybe you can see where is my mistake.

Comment: To determine the sign of "the function", please provide "the function"  You've simply provided an inequality.

Comment: "maybe you can see where is my mistake" Indeed I can... One cannot pass from $\frac{2}{3x-1}≥\frac{2}{x^{2}-1}$ to $\frac{2x^{2}-2}{3x-1}≥2$ without assuming that $x^2-1>0$ -- and this is not guaranteed, right?

Comment: @amWhy this is the only information of the problem...

Comment: @Did ah, thanks man. I got it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ \frac{2}{3x-1} \geq \frac{1}{x-1}-\frac{1}{x+1} \Longleftrightarrow \frac{2}{3x-1} \geq \frac{2}{(x-1)(x+1)} $$

$$ \Longleftrightarrow \frac{1}{3x-1} - \frac{1}{(x-1)(x+1)} \geq 0 \Longleftrightarrow \frac{(x-1)(x+1)-(3x-1)}{(3x-1)(x-1)(x+1)} \geq0 $$

$$ \Longleftrightarrow \frac{x^2-3x}{(3x-1)(x-1)(x+1)} \geq 0 
\Longleftrightarrow \frac{x(x-3)}{(3x-1)(x-1)(x+1)} \geq 0 $$

Comment: In the 3° step, how did the number two turned into a number 1?

Comment: You can divide both sides by 2 as it is greater than 0

Comment: oh, thanks man, haha. Got it

Answer (score 0):

It should be $\frac{x(x-3)}{(3x-1)(x-1)(x+1)}\geq0$

Comment: How did you get this answer?

Comment: @Nicolas Leskiu Just $\frac{2}{3x-1}-\frac{1}{x-1}+\frac{1}{x+1}=\frac{2x^2-2-3x^2-2x+1+3x^2-4x+1}{(3x-1)(x-1)(x+1)}=\frac{2x(x-3)}{(3x-1)(x-1)(x+1)}$